# Prody for modeling protein structure python

Tags: python, modeling, protein-database

Can we use ProDy to model the structure of proteins? Is there any other way we can model the structure of a protein using Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ProDy may do the job.

If you like using "only" Python, then check aslo PyMOL (http://www.pymol.org/)
for visualizing proteins and molecular structures.

If you like to run simulations, then GROMACS package for molecular dynamics simulations will be my choice, but it is written (mainly) in C.

http://www.gromacs.org/